# Binding to DataGridTemplateColumn using style applied within DataTemplate?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, styles, datatemplate

I have a `ComboBox` that composes a `DataTemplate`, and I'm having trouble binding its `IsEnabled` property to the `IsReadOnly` property on the templated `DataGridTemplateColumn`.

I've been receiving the following error in my VS output window:

> *'IsReadOnly' property not found on 'object' ''ContentPresenter'*

**ComboBox style:**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" x:Key="ProficiencyColumnComboBoxStyle">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" 
        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent},
        Path=IsReadOnly, Converter={StaticResource BooleanOppositeConverter}}" />
</Style>
```

I believe the problem is with how I specify the `RelativeSource` intended to identify my `DataGridColumn`. I've tried:

- `RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}`
- `RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridColumn}`
- `RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridTemplateColumn}`

I've tried adding other setters to this style, and they do take effect, so I know the style and `DataTemplate` are being applied to the controls.

**P.S.**

I've used this same technique to bind another `ComboBox` within a `DataTemplate` to a property on the parent `DataGrid` of its templated columns. **The difference is that here I'm using a converter, and trying to bind to a property on a column** (instead of the grid.) However, even if I remove the converter from the above style, no binding takes place.

Comment: Can't bind to the columns like that, they are not ojects in the logical or visual tree, they are just data, hence RelativeSource will fail. You should [debug the binding](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx), surely you get a binding error.

Comment: @H.B. That's an excellent article, hanks for the heads up! The binding error found in my output window is present in the question... if you're aware of a workaround or alternative approach to achieving my goal, please post an answer and I'd be glad to accept.

Comment: That is the error you get for TemplatedParent i assume, for bindings to the column you should get something about the source not being found. Anyway, usually you can only bind to DG columns using `Binding.Source` in combination with [`x:Reference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795380.aspx), there may be complications with cyclical dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" x:Key="ProficiencyColumnComboBoxStyle">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" 
            Value="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanOppositeConverter}}"/>
</Style>
```

DataGridCell.IsReadOnly should pick up value from its DataGridColumn.IsReadOnly.

Answer (score 1):

Creating the column as a resource might work out, that way you might be able to use `StaticResource` to target it. e.g.

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Key="Column" .../>
</DataGrid.Resources>
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="Column"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

```
{Binding IsReadOnly, Source={StaticResource Column}}
```

---

As mentioned in a comment `Binding.Source` and [`x:Reference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795380.aspx) via the name of the column might work as well, depending on the structure. If you can move the part with the reference into the resources of the element being referenced you can usually get rid of cyclical dependecy errors. You just need to use the `StaticResource` extension in the place where that part is needed, not all too convenient.

Comment: +1 for the informative answer. Sorry for not accepting as I stated in the comments, but Stipo provided a concise working answer, while this approach would require restructuring my XAML. Will likely use this in the future :)

Comment: @robjb: That's a pretty interesting idea i have to say, deserved accept.